# How to solve "undefined symbol: av_top_index

Tags: python, perl, python-3.7

I am trying to use a python module called pyperler, which uses cython internally, and it needs to be compiled, I have managed to compile it and install it in a non default location (the default location is a non writeable NFS share) and in order for python to "see" it I am using the "imp" module to which I pass the path to where pyperler was installed. But when I try to use it in a trivial test python program, I get the error "undefined symbol: av_top_index"

Below is the test python program code

```
import sys, os, imp

install_dir = ".../pyperler_installation_dir/pyperler-0.2-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg/"
my_module_file = os.path.join(install_dir, "pyperler.py")

pyperler = imp.load_source('pyperler', my_module_file)

import pyperler; i = pyperler.Interpreter()
print(i)
print(type(pyperler) )
```

and the error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 6, in <module>
    pyperler = imp.load_source('pyperler', my_module_file)
  File ".../python/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File ".../pyperler_installation_dir/pyperler-0.2-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pyperler.py", line 7, in <module>
    __bootstrap__()
  File ".../pyperler_installation_dir/pyperler-0.2-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pyperler.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
    imp.load_dynamic(__name__,__file__)
  File ".../200105/python/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 670, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 583, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1043, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: .../pyperler_installation_dir/pyperler-0.2-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pyperler.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: av_top_index
```

The OS is Oracle linux 7.7
Python version is: 3.7.4
GCC version is: 4.8.5
perl version is: 5.28

The command I used to compile the pyperler module is:

```
sudo PYTHONPATH=.../pyperler_installation_dir/ su -c ' .../user_python-conversion/python/bin/python3 setup.py install --root=".../pyperler_installation_dir/"'
```

Does anybody know how to solve this error?

Comment: If this is a mounted NFS, you should be able to see it in `/mnt`, right? Otherwise, I'm not sure if `...` is valid syntax for `os` to traverse a directory

Comment: sure it is not, I am not putting the full path, just a part of it and the rest I tried to represent it with the "..." but in the real program it is a valid path

Comment: According to [perldelta](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.18.0/perldelta.html) `av_top_index()` was introduced in  Perl version 5.18. So if the Perl library is older than that you would get an undefined symbol error

Comment: You get that error when a Perl module with C components was compiled by a different build of Perl (e.g. a different version of Perl) than the one trying to load it (i.e. the one embedded by pyperler).